# Unrecognised Partial Derivative Notation

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm trying to brush up on my calculus for my job search and I'm really struggling to understand something basic that is frustrating me. The question is given by:

If w $\in \mathbb{R}^d$ and x $\in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $f(w) = sin(x^Tw)$, find
$\frac{\partial f(w)}{\partial w}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 f(w)}{\partial w\partial w^T}$

Now I'm pretty sure I can get the first derivative correctly at $x^Tcos(x^Tw)$ but I'm struggling to understand the notation of the second derivative, in particular $\partial w\partial w^T$. Am I correct in saying that this question is asking for the derivative with respect to W of the derivative with respect to $w^T$? But, how does one find this $w^T$ to begin with?

Comment: In this case, notice that since $x^Tw$ is a scalar (it is a dot product) we have that $x^Tw = w^Tx$. Can you finish the partial derivative now? (Hint: if you're confused about order at the end of this computation, is the end result supposed to be a scalar, vector, or a matrix?)

Comment: Okay, I wasn't thinking of this correctly. Am I correct in saying it will be a vector? This will then change the first partial into taking $\frac{\partial^2 f(w)}{\partial w^T}$, which we find, then take it with respect to w from there?

Comment: Using "@ username" will make sure that the other person gets a notification when you post. To answer your question, not quite, you can't have a partial squared up top and just one derivative on the bottom. It will not be a vector. Your choices are either scalar or matrix (which is it?)